# Update method of Observer Design Pattern

Tags: c#, java, design-patterns

I have seen few examples of Observer pattern.

Why does the update method in the Observer interface in some cases include a reference to the object being observed?
Doesn't the observer know what object it is observing?

Please explain with example.

Comment: I agree that's not common. Especially since the update() method of the observer is usually called by the observable object when it has to notify its state change. Can you post the example that causes you doubt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may or may not have a reference to the Subject, depending on the concrete problem.

The Subject might only call the update() function and just set some value in the Observer, thus the Observer does not need a reference. Or it can notify the Observer that there has been a change, and the Observer will contact the Subject by the reference it has and get the new values.

Holding the reference in the implementation can also be used if the Observers have need to inform the Subject about something.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically to your last question, given C# and Java as programming languages, how would one object "know" about another object, except via a reference?

The relationship between an observer and a subject needs to be stored somewhere, and in Java and C# can only be stored via references, if any actions need to be invoked on either the subject or the observer.

Comment: Good Point. Sometimes, the programming language syntax & semantics, may change how a design pattern may be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Amandeep you can read this article it's very interessant, you have all design patterns of GOF

You have class diagram, sample code

It explain all concepts about observation : Subject, ConcreteSubject, Observer and ConcreteObserver

http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One `Observer` can observe many `Observable` so when he gets notified it can handle the change in a specific manner. For example :

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class ObserverSample {
    static class ObservableExtension extends Observable {
        void doSomething() {
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers();
            clearChanged();
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final ObservableExtension observable1 = new ObservableExtension();
        final Observable observable2 = new ObservableExtension();
        final Observer observer = new Observer() {
            @Override
            public void update(final Observable o, final Object arg) {
                if (o == observable1)
                    System.out.println("This is the first observable");
                else if (o == observable1)
                    System.out.println("This is the second observable");
                else
                    System.out.println("This is another observable");
            }
        };
        observable1.addObserver(observer);
        observable2.addObserver(observer);
        observable1.doSomething();
    }
}
```

However, i don't like this approach (
The sole advantage is a smaller memory footprint.), I prefer having different Observer with a single responsability.

```
    observable1.addObserver(new Observer() {
        @Override
        public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
            System.out.println("This is the first observable");
        }
    });
    observable2.addObserver(new Observer() {
        @Override
        public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
            System.out.println("This is the second observable");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick Short Answer

There can be several variations of the Observer Pattern.

One of them allows only to detect changes of the observed objects, and maybe display their properties values. Other allows to perform an operation also.